# Some plugins don't work after Android Studio upgrade 4.1-- Plugin is incompatible supported only in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-4.1

Some plugins don't work after Android Studio upgrade 4.1, but these plugins work in 4.0. Does anyone know what to do?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio 4.1 Plugin Error: Plugin \* is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64347831/android-studio-4-1-plugin-error-plugin-is-incompatible-supported-only-in-int)

Comment: **Create Parcelable class without plugin in Android Studio**

implements Parcelable in your class and then put cursor on "implements Parcelable" and hit Alt+Enter and select Add Parcelable implementation.
That's it.

[Screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbGOs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAC OS
open Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/plugins/
create folder
example parcelable/lib/parcelable.jar

Windows
[Android Studio 4.1 Plugin Error: Plugin * is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64347831/android-studio-4-1-plugin-error-plugin-is-incompatible-supported-only-in-int/64348251)