# Android Studio 4.1 Plugin Error: Plugin * is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, plugins

**Plugin Error**

*Plugin "Android WiFi ADB" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA). Plugin "Name That Color" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA). Plugin "Json2Pojo" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA).*

I tried to install the plugin "Android WiFi ADB", "Name That Color", "Android WiFi ADB", etc in Android Studio 4.1, but I faced this error. Can anyone help me with this?

Errors screenshot

[image: 1]

#### Software Detail

> Android Studio 4.1
>
> Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6858069, built on September 23, 2020
>
> Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64
>
> VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
>
> Windows 10 10.0
>
> GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
>
> Memory: 1246M
>
> Cores: 4
>
> Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
>
> Non-Bundled Plugins: com.thoughtworks.gauge, org.intellij.plugins.markdown, org.jetbrains.kotlin

Comment: I'm using linux, solved by removing folder: `AndroidWiFiADB`  from path: `/home/p2pdops/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1`...

Answer (score 151):

Some older plugins are no longer compatible with the latest Android Studio (4.1 right now). Also, they seem to have changed the location of the plugins folder with this new version.

**You will have to uninstall the plugin. In my case, I couldn't see the plugin listed in the IDE settings. I had to manually find and delete the file.**

Currently, plugins are located in the following directories (make sure to change the android version number in the path if your software version is different; versions below 3 are located differently as detailed [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config)):

**Windows** (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in the explorer then paste it): `%APPDATA%\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins`

**MacOS:**
 `~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins`

**linux:** `~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins` or `~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/`

Delete the plugins there and the error should be gone.

Comment: Can someone guide me to the new plugin location in MacOS?

Comment: Yeah but how can we use those plugins again?

Comment: @SamirElekberov You're gonna have to wait for their developers to update them.

Comment: It is absolutely backward thinking to move the plugin folder location and not listing inside the IDE Plugin settings the actual incompatible plugin for us to easily remove it without fussing around the app data files. It knows it is incompatible, it knows better than us where it is, why on earth would it not list it in the plugin settings for us to decide whether to remove it or disable it is beyond me.

Comment: @Rohit `~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins` for mac

Comment: Thanks @wangqi060934. Found it!

Comment: @SamirElekberov see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64464679/7772358

Comment: @nandur93 That doesnt work.. I just waited for developers to update them.. Then it worked.

Comment: After updating to AS 4.2 it automatically takes care of this and does not copy unsupported plugins to new version's plugin folder :)

Comment: there is no such plugin! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70361299/plugin-error-plugin-is-compatible-with-intellij-idea-only-because-it-doesnt

Comment: Upvoted. On Windows WIN+L is the login screen, you probably mean WIN+E

Comment: @adrianvintu its ctrl+L not Win+L. Ctrl+L shifts focus to the address bar when inside the explorer.

Comment: @Asim oh, i never used that before, thanks. also, misread on my part, sorry :D

Answer (score 55):

1. Download the plugin by going to Android Studio File/Setting/Plugins search for Android Wifi ADB and install it.
2. Now You may found AndroidWiFiADB Folder at path ==>  **C:\Users\PCUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio\Plugins** , Cut the Android Wifi ADB Folder.
3. Now Paste That AndroidWiFiADB Folder at path ==>  **C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins**
4. Restart Android Studio And Enjoy Debugging through WiFi.

Comment: This worked for me , had to provide write permission to plugins folder otherwise it was copying in C drive only

Comment: This worked for me also .My Android studio version "Arctic fox version 2020.3.1 patch 4"

Comment: Worked for me as well! cheers!

Comment: Android Studio 2022.3 silently ignores such copied plugin.

Answer (score 22):

I've just updated the studio to `4.1` and got the same issue with the above-mentioned libraries. Below is my approach to fix this without rely on a third party in the case of `ADB WIFi` and **for other plugins we need to wait developer to make changes according to the latest android studio**.

**Connect to a device over Wi-Fi (Android 10 and lower)**

**Step 1:**

```
Connect the device to the host computer with a USB cable.
```

**Step 2:**

```
Set the target device to listen for a TCP/IP connection on port 5555
 adb tcpip 5555
```

**Step 3:**

```
Disconnect the USB cable from the target device.
```

**Step 4:**

```
Find the IP address of the Android device. For example, on a Nexus device, 
you can find the IP address at Settings > About tablet (or About phone) > Status > IP address. Or, on a Wear OS device, you can find the IP address at Settings > Wi-Fi Settings > Advanced > IP address.
```

**Step 5:**

```
Connect to the device by its IP address
 adb connect device_ip_address
```

**Step 8:**

```
Confirm that your host computer is connected to the target device: 
adb devices
```

Comment: step 4 (alternative):
Show IP address of the devices that are connected via wifi

adb shell ip addr show wlan0

Answer (score 12):

1. Go to this directory.
2. Find the plugin name and remove its folder totally.

Note: 'AppData' is a hidden folder by default.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

For windows :

1. Download plugin zip file manually from [official website](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/androidstudio)
2. unzip the zip file and paste it in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins
3. Restart your Android Studio

For getting rid of that incompatible plugins warning, you can follow [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64348251/8472272) (by @asim), if your are not able to see AppData folder then it means it is in hidden items.

Comment: Worked for me. plugins folder is not in AppData for my install in a custom folder. With Android Studio 4.1 the plugin folder is inside Android Studio install directory as noted in this answer.

Comment: yaaaa! that work for me. i want to use "android clean code generator" and "android wifi adb" plugins.

Comment: This worked for me , had to provide write permission to plugins folder otherwise it was copying in C drive only

Answer (score 9):

Plugins directory on MacOS:

```
/Users/{username}/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins
```

Just remove the plugin from this directory.

Answer (score 5):

You need to wait for the plugin developer to add support for the new android studio version and then update plugins or install the old android studio

Comment: In my case, I missed <depends>com.intellij.modules.androidstudio</depends> in plugins.xml file. Without it, it was working till AS 4.0, but for AS 4.0+, that declaration seems mandatory.

Answer (score 5):

MAC OS:

1. Download the plugin to local.
2. Unzip the plugin(.zip),you will see a folder named 'lib' which contains jars.
3. Right click the AndroidStuido icon, select "show package contents”.
4. Enter Contents/plugins directory, and make a new folder.
5. Then copy the 'lib' folder to the new folder.
6. Restart your AS.
7. Enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

Solution for Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1) on macOS (should probably be not too different on Windows parring the path).

Yes Arctic Fox is version "2020.3".. it took me a while to realize that I wasn't on version 4.2 and I was actually on this version. I don't know why they chose "2020.3" for their version number for a 2021 update but whatever.

cd into this pwd:

> cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3/plugins

delete AndroidWiFiADB

> rm -rf AndroidWiFiADB

Search for the Android Wifi ADB plugin on [plugins.Jetbrains](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?products=androidstudio) or whatever plugin you want, it's this one [here for Android Wifi ADB](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7983-android-wifi-adb) and download the zip file for the latest version manually.

Unzip it.

open the Android Studio plugins directory which lies in the / root directory with this command

> open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/plugins

Paste the unzipped folder here and restart your IDE. And voila! The Android Wifi ADB (or whatever plugin you were having issues with installing) now works!

Answer (score 2):

We have such problem with new Android Studio 4.1 with custom plugin. Plugin supplied as zip archive.
Following steps solve it:

1. Unzip plugin manually into **Android Studio/Contents/plugins** (our plugin called *exporter*). You should have such structure: **Android Studio/Contents/plugins/exporter/lib/somejars**
   [image]
2. Restart Android Studio
3. **Plugin works!**

P.S. **For plugin developers.** Our plugin intellij version (in *build.gradle* file):

```
intellij {
    version 'IU-201.6668.121'
}
```

Comment: When I changed interllij.version to 'IU-201.6668.121' it did solve the problem, but after upgrading android studio 4.1.1 the problem recurred, how do I fix it, please?

Answer (score 2):

**For Macbook Users**

*Download the plugin by going to Android Studio File/Setting/Plugins search for Android Wifi ADB and install it.*

Now You may find AndroidWiFiADB Folder at path ==>

```
/Users/userName/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2022.2/plugins 
Cut the Android Wifi ADB Folder.
```

Now Paste That AndroidWiFiADB Folder at path ==> `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins`

Restart Android Studio And Enjoy Debugging through WiFi.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad my code worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

MAC OS

1. open Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/plugins/
2. create folder
3. example parcelable/lib/parcelable.jar

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most effective method to **fix** the old plugins:
1- Delete the old jar file (bonus point: cut & paste it somewhere else and keep it for the next step) from this location (Thanks [@Asim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64348251/3082007) for the location):

```
C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins
```

2- In Android Studio go to File -> Settings -> Plugins.
There are 2 tabs here: `Marketplace` and `Installed`. forget them! Click the gear icon next to the `Installed` tab. choose `Install plugin from disk...`. locate your jar file from the previous step or redownload it from the official marketplace manually (in my case: [this plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7332-android-parcelable-code-generator))

Done. Enjoy your favorite plugin.

- Bonus tip: Android studio may still keep showing errors about compatibility issues. in my case, some plugins worked fine and some plugins (looking at you `Butterknife Zelezny`!) crashed and broke the syntax highlighting system! who uses that feature, right? unless you actually code in the android studio directly and don't copy & paste from StackOverflow! anyway, if you ended up in some weird situation and you don't know who to blame, good news! Android studio got your back! make sure to check the android studio log file here: `C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\log\idea.log`
  And see if any plugin is causing instability (look for the `Plugin to blame` phrase in the log file if there is any)

Answer (score 0):

Mac:

~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins

find and delete the bad plugin folder

restart android studio

Answer (score 0):

I'd that issue and solving it by

1. Remove that plugin if it still exists in android studio plugins
2. Install it again.

I had tried that and worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Mac：
Delete the entire folder。

（/Users/XXX/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1）

reboot android studio，and reset AS。now  you can install AS plugins。

Windows should do the same

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Dimenify plugin and the error kept showing even after remove the folder from 'plugins' directory.

The solution that worked for me, from marketplace:

1. Reinstall the plugin
2. Disable it

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have this problem as a new type **Plugin Error** and Android Studio never open:
[image]

Then I found solution:

> If you are using Sourcetree, close it. Then, open Android Studio. Then, open Sourcetree.