# How solve android studio 4.1 "Vector Icon Pack is incompatible" problem?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile

After update into this version in every run shown this event log.

> Plugin Error: Plugin "Vector Icon Pack" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA).

***problem is, I can't find this plugin to remove it**

Comment: Android Studio is not a full IntelliJ IDEA, so don't try to load a plugin that requires the full IntelliJ IDEA into Android Studio. Find a plugin that's compatible with Android Studio (if that exists).

Comment: problem is here, I can't  find  this plugin  to remove it

Comment: I am having the same problem. Tried to add and now I can't remove it. It shows the annoying message every time I start Android Studio. But in plugin installer I see this is already uninstalled

Comment: Finally, delete that in this location [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64348251/10242802)