# Android Studio 4.1 - Plugin "Install Apk" is incompatible

Tags: android-studio, plugins, intellij-14

Since upgrading to AS 4.1 from 4.0 I get the event log message

```
Plugin Error: Plugin "Install Apk" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA).
```

on starting AS.

Yes, this is like a previous report[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64347831/android-studio-4-1-plugin-error-plugin-is-incompatible-supported-only-in-int), but this appears to be a bundled plugin. I don't think it's anything I've added, nor can I find anything obviously out of place either in the list of plugins under settings nor in the plugins directory.

Installing APKs does indeed not work, so it is a problem rather than a nuisance.

How do I track down where it's coming from, and even better, fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for that plugin and delete it manually at this directory:
`C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins`
Besides this, It is not a problem. Android Studio just shows a dialog and cant use plugin. There is no problem except disturbing you. You can just wait for plugin's update for compatibility.

Comment: Interesting.
To my surprise I did find a plugin file (InstallAPK.jar at /~/.AndroidStudio4.0/config/plugins/ since I'm on Linux)

It's this https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12890-install-apk, but it doesn't show up in my list of installed Plugins. Deleting the file had... no effect!. AS stil complained about it when loading! Whut?

Comment: It is not a plugin that you can use.. It is default file. You shouldn't do anything to that file. Look at this directory: 
 /home/**YOUR_USERNAME**/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/

Comment: You're a star @samir! That did it, thank you. I have removed (moved but I'm now not sure where I put it) that first file, bur presumably that's not a problem (?)

I don't suppose I can mark a comment as the right answer so I'll mark the answer as correct. Thanks again!

Comment: I am glad to help.. Thank you too my friend. (you can just like my answer and comment)

Answer (score 0):

To make plugins work with the new version of Android Studio "4.1"

1- install the plugin

2- extract it

3- move folder to

> C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins

4- restart Android Studio

Comment: Hi @Momen, I'm afraid I don't understand your answer.
What do you mean by "extract it"?
And, although I only it said in my comments above, I'm running this under Linux, not Windows

Comment: Hi,
extract it means un-archive it

Comment: Thank you for that, but I still don't understand. Why "extract it" after installing it? perhaps you mean "download it"? My question wasn't about adding a plugin, it was about removing one that appears not to work after upgrading AS. @Sami's answer(s) work.

Comment: Oh ok, my answer is about making the plugin works on the new android studio, it's a little tricky