# WIFI ADB ULTIMATE doesn't work in Android Studio 4 and above

Tags: android, plugins, android-studio-4.0

I have not been able to use the [WIFI ADB ULTIMATE](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9207-wifi-adb-ultimate) plugin since updating Android Studio to version 4. Shows the following error when running Android Studio.

```
Plugin Error: Plugin "WIFI ADB ULTIMATE" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA).
```

Isn't Android Studio an IntelliJ IDEA?

How can I use this plugin in Android Studio 4 and above?
This plugin was very hassle-free and effective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Android Studio 4.1 Plugin Error: Plugin * is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64347831/android-studio-4-1-plugin-error-plugin-is-incompatible-supported-only-in-int)

check this link

btw i replaced this with ADB Wifi by Yury Polek, its a good alternative and works well.

Comment: thank you. I found a better plugin. Android WiFiADB.

Comment: I don't think its better than WIFI ADB Ultimate, because when I connect via IP Address is not connecting. When I am using WIFI ADB Ultimate only one time connect via usb last 6months after that connect via IP address only. I can't carry the usb cable.

Comment: thanks, it's working perfectly