# Plugin "Fabric for Android Studio" is incompatible

Tags: android-studio, google-fabric, jetbrains-toolbox

Since updating to Android Studio 4.1 I constantly get this error message on startup:

> Plugin Error: Plugin "Fabric for Android Studio" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA).

That plugin is neither listed in Settings > Plugins nor is it not contained in [the expected path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64348251/549372).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After downloading "Fabric for Android Studio", it turned out that it is called `CrashlyticsPlugin`.
And when searching for `CrashlyticsPlugin` it turned out, that the JetBrains Toolbox uses different paths than the standalone installer does. Removing all occurrences of the `CrashlyticsPlugin` from `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\AndroidStudio\` `ch-0` and `ch-1` solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks, this worked on my end as well. On Linux, the `ch-0` folder is located in `~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/` by default.

Comment: For me, I had to delete `~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/CrashlyticsPlugin`

Comment: In Windows 10 with AndroidStudio 4.1.2 I have deleted directory "CrashlyticsPlugin" in path "C:\Users\\(userName)\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins".
I have solved the problem (1 year waited solution).

Comment: in windows 10, with AS 4.1.3, deletin from C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins work for me !

Comment: in windows CMD+R -> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins get to the folder!

Comment: in MacOS I had to delete _CrashlyticsPlugin_ directory from `~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio{X}/plugins`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `Enable/ Disable` from Android Studio
Go to `File -> Settings -> Plugins`

If you want to remove incompatible plugins manually, just go to the plugin path and delete the particular folder.

*AndroidStudio Plugins default path:*

```
**Windows:**
%appdata%\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins

**MacOS:**
/Users/{username}/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins
```