# Plugin 'Fabric for Android Studio' is compatible with IntelliJ IDEA only because it doesn't define any explicit module dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, android-studio-bumblebee, android-studio-plugin

I don't have 'Fabric for android studio' installed
but this error always appear in my AS

this is the alert
[alert plugin fabric for android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfnsI.png)

this is my plugin in AS
[list of plugins in my AS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGq8P.png)

and this is my plugins folder and its contents
[list of plugins in my folder (AndroidStudio2021.1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZY8M.png)

please tell me, how to fix it or how to remove it from my AS ?
thank you

Comment: i'm sorry
i've fixed this problem with this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65665159/7693381
thanks before

Comment: yaps, i don't know 'fabric for android' turned out that it is called CrashlyticsPlugin, so i delete CrashlyticsPlugin in my plugins folder manually.
btw thanks before @AbhishekDutt