# Plugin Error: Plugin "Json2Dart" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: flutter, android-studio-4.1

I am developing a flutter app using android studio 4.1.2 but this plugin Error pops up everytime and i could find a solution for it. what do you think i should do.

Comment: try updating Json2Dart plugin. In Android Studio Help > Check for Update

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64347831/android-studio-4-1-plugin-error-plugin-is-incompatible-supported-only-in-int) answer IDE is no longer can see the plugin in list of plugins, but there is a file in your system. You need to manually delete this plugin. There is path to plugin directory:

**Windows** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in the explorer then paste it): `%APPDATA%\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins`

**MacOS**:  `~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins`

**linux**: `~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins or ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1`/