# Plugin error: Plugin * is compatible with IntelliJ IDEA only because it doesn't define any explicit module dependencies

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-arctic-fox

I installed such plugin once and now I get this error, I tried to delete everything related to it but still this error, plugins folder doesn't include files of that plugin:

> Plugin error: Plugin 'Google Sceneform Tools (Beta)' is compatible
> with IntelliJ IDEA only because it doesn't define any explicit module
> dependencies

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Install the plugin again and delete it not just by unchecking it but as follows:

1. Open Preferences -> Plugins
2. Install Plugin again through "Marketplace"
3. Switch to "Installed" tab and right-click on the plugin
4. Click "Uninstall...", Apply and Restart IDE

[image]

Comment: Intelligible, but does not work. Restarting android studio once again produces the error. Can you tell me what the alert is caused by?

Comment: Hey @Kreidol, 
i'm sorry but I don't know what the alert is caused by. I just tried around a bit and these steps helped in my case.

Answer (score 2):

bro go to C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\plugins\google-sceneform-tools. you delete here and restart your project

Comment: Any equivalent for MacOS?