# The error on plugin of Android Studio of ADB WIFI

Tags: android, plugins, adb

two errors always appear when I start Android Studio,I also checked the plugin manager,I have delete the follow plugin,Can someone answer this question for me, it was tiny and I just want to known why?

```
Plugin 'ADB Android Debug - Remote Device/Remote Cloud Mobile' is compatible with IntelliJ IDEA only because it doesn't define any explicit module dependencies
Plugin 'ADB WiFi Connect' is compatible with IntelliJ IDEA only because it doesn't define any explicit module dependencies
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem has solved by this anwser
[enter link description here][1]
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70361299/plugin-error-plugin-is-compatible-with-intellij-idea-only-because-it-doesnt